# Cap the highest values in a list so that the sum equals a given number

Tags: code-golf, number

A slightly more challenging one compared to my previous challenge. Given a list of positive integers (>0) and the positive integer `m`, output a list of positive integers that are capped values of the input values so that the sum of the capped values equals `m`. Cap the highest values first. And keep the same order.

**Cases**

(Given 'list' and 'sum' output 'list')

- Given `4, 2` and `6` output `4, 2` no capping needed (ncn), keep order (ko)
- Given `2, 4` and `6` output `2, 4` ncn, ko
- Given `3, 3` and `6` output `3, 3` ncn
- Given `3, 3` and `7` output `3, 3` ncn

Then this:

- Given `4, 2` and `5` output `3, 2` cap the highest (cth), ko
- Given `2, 4` and `5` output `2, 3` cth, ko
- Given `3, 3` and `5` output `3, 2` or `2, 3` cap any of the highest (cath)

Then this:

- Given `5, 4, 2` and `10` output `4, 4, 2` cth, ko
- Given `2, 4, 5` and `10` output `2, 4, 4` cth, ko
- Given `4, 4, 2` and `7` output `3, 2, 2` or `2, 3, 2` cth, cath, ko
- Given `4, 2, 4` and `7` output `3, 2, 2` or `2, 2, 3` cth, cath, ko

Then this:

- Given `4, 4, 2` and `5` output `2, 2, 1` or any permutation (oap)
- Given `2, 4, 4` and `5` output `1, 2, 2` oap
- Given `4, 4, 2` and `4` output `1, 2, 1` oap
- Given `2, 4, 4` and `4` output `1, 1, 2` oap
- Given `70, 80, 90` and `10` output `3, 3, 4` oap

Then this:

- Given `4, 2, 4` and `2` output an error or a falsy value, because the sum of 3 positive integers cannot be 2.

**Rules**

- Both input and output are all about positive integers (>0)
- The number of values in the input and output list are equal.
- The sum of the output values is exactly equal to `m` or less than `m` only if the sum of the input values was already lower.
- If the sum of the values in the input list is already lower then or equal to `m`, no capping is needed. (ncn)
- Cap the highest values first (cth)
- When multiple values are the highest value and equally high, it doesn't matter which you cap. (cath)
- The capped values in the output list have to be in the same order as their original values in the input list. (ko)
- When at some point (thinking iteratively) all values are equally high, it stops being important which you cap.
- If there's no solution output an error or a falsy value.

**The winner**

The shortest valid answer - measured in bytes - wins.

Apart form the rules, I'm interested to see a program that keeps a value intact as long as possible. Consider the input values a plant each with the heights `10,2,10` and the maximum `m`=5, it would be a waste to cap the baby plant in the middle.

Comment: -1 for "no recursion". It makes this difficult if not impossible for many languages (not just esolangs), it's an ambiguous and unobservable requirement and I don't think it adds anything to the challenge.

Comment: What are the allowable answers to `3, 2` and `3`?

Comment: Could you add a test case for when `m` is greater than the total?

Comment: Could you also explain the rules more clearly? I cant quite understand the ko rule - in the `4,4,2` and `5` case are you capping the `2` to `1` or are you capping one of the `4`s to a `1` and then rearranging the items to match the input in some way? (note that if it is done iteratively we reach `2,2,2` at which point we can cath and yield `1,2,2` following all the other rules).

Comment: @JonathanAllan Your right. When at some point (thinking iteratively) all are an even height,
 it stops being important which you cap.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen `1, 2` and `2, 1`. If many can be capped it doesn't matter which you cap.

Comment: The "no recursion" requirement has been removed after it was commented on right after I published the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 17 bytes

```
œṡṀ‘jṀ’µS>⁴µ¿¹0Ạ?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///o5Ic7Fz7c2fCoYUYWmJp5aGuw3aPGLYe2Htp/aKfBw10L7P///29uoGNhoGNp8N/QAAA)

Uses iterative approach: repetitively subtract 1 from the highest element.

```
œṡṀ‘jṀ’µS>⁴µ¿¹0Ạ? - Main link. First input list, second input integer.
           µ¿       - While:
        S             - Sum of the list
         >            - greater than
          ⁴           - second input 
       µ            - Do: 
œṡ                    - split list by first occurrence of 
  Ṁ                   - the maximum element
   ‘                  - increment all
    j                 - join by
     Ṁ                - maximum element
      ’               - increment
                ?   - If:
               Ạ      - no elements are non-zero
             ¹        - Then: output the list
              0       - Else: return 0.
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <strike>70</strike> <strike>77</strike> 56 bytes

<sup>-21 bytes thanks to [Jonathan Allan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/53748/jonathan-allan)!</sup>

```python
def f(l,n):
 while n/all(l)<sum(l):l[l.index(max(l))]-=1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVDLboMwEDzDV@wNW9q0hEdpUdJTe@gvFHGIGqNY2tjIkIR8PbUdoFx62tl5Haa99yet0nE8igYaRqh4GcLtJEmAej4QMeK77nK2p6SKnqQ6ioGdD4MleL3Zb8dGG7A5UBykAsaqDJMaXziyKsFsQimma1Q45H354ssX1aMcvb6NJwPm85M9lLnDZYsVPzcunROfrXiPixhfY3yL/3p9V8LtAgF9KdgDVWUdBr25WyZ4rBMGYvgRbQ/fwugPeZWd1OrTGG2cpzVS9YzZtBsEIdq8g3Bi5ILUiX9MEQLx8Rc)

Comment: @JonathanAllan I added a fix for the latter case that didn't change the byte count. I also am unsure about the first issue seeing as it doesn't line up with an iterative approach to reducing values. I will await further clarification prior to making a fix.

Comment: This answer is fine now. Check the update of my question

Comment: Save 11 bytes with `while n/all(l)<sum(l):l[l.index(max(l))]-=1`

Comment: ...in fact [meta consensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4942/53748) is that return values may be modified inputs passed by reference, like `l` here, so [this](https://tio.run/##dVDLboMwEDzDV@wNW9q0hEdpUdJTe@gvFHGIGqNY2tjIkIR8PbUdoFx62tl5Haa99yet0nE8igYaRqh4GcLtJEmAej4QMeK77nK2p6SKnqQ6ioGdD4MleL3Zb8dGG7A5UBykAsaqDJMaXziyKsFsQimma1Q45H354ssX1aMcvb6NJwPm85M9lLnDZYsVPzcunROfrXiPixhfY3yL/3p9V8LtAgF9KdgDVWUdBr25WyZ4rBMGYvgRbQ/fwugPeZWd1OrTGG2cpzVS9YzZtBsEIdq8g3Bi5ILUiX9MEQLx8Rc) saves another 10 bytes

Comment: @JonathanAllan Nice! I don't know why this didn't occur to me earlier.

Answer (score 3):

## PHP>=7.1, 94 bytes

```php
<?for([$a,$s]=$_GET;array_sum($a)>$s;)$a[array_flip($a)[max($a)]]--;print_r(min($a)?$a:0);
```

replace `array_flip($a)[max($a)]` with `array_search(max($a),$a)` to cap the last/first item with the maximum value

[PHP Sandbox Online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c0c34f3f4c0e3be138654d790bb8b1496497a88d)

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 79 bytes

```
(u:=Plus@@a;For[a=#2,u>#,a[[#&@@a~Position~Max@a]]--];Min@a>0&&u==#||Quit[];a)&
```

Takes `sum` and `List of integers`

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 53 bytes

`c` takes an integer and a list of integers, returning a list of integers. Use as `c 6 [4,2]`.

```hs
c n=until((<=n).sum)f
f(x:y)|any(>x)y=x:f y|x>1=x-1:y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY/NboMwEITvPMU2ysFWHJQfaFoLcql6qNRemmNaVSgxiVVYI2NUkPLu1DgFmpUsze58nrXPSfktsqyVeaG0gSeFRqvMf64PojBSoeflicQ4T4q3L0I@iGRIYb6Fo/LAVlGZndEwhfKsfjqT8xc0dDabdNDEMQaiORjdWEoLU2mE6R0cAEE6@5CUwjIqdV1X7/J0toMuodASrRysV5EaEKNDBOc7lYvhvZRa1tciOVI/kyjKOIpOwnT/EmjK1u6NKzQyIySKkfplldPUS0nNG3pJsCHbmjZxzVNoLvV2GdfzJW/aluwDBqtPdk89sl8xCP7kmsH6Rm46eWXDkQ1HwMnQTh2zXPQQg7Bvg94dwlzI5sYLx4v9gsELbjzXbRYMHux5XPzbcs1d0V8)

## How it works

- `c n` applies `f` to its (implicit) list argument until its sum is `<= n`.
- `f` takes and returns a list of integers. It finds the first maximum value in the list by recursing, and then reduces it by 1, unless the maximum is `<=1`, in which case a non-exhaustive patterns error is raised.

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>61</s> 56 bytes

*-5 bytes thanks to Leaky Nun*

```r
function(l,s){while(sum(l)>s)l[which.max(l)]=max(l)-1;l}
```

Anonymous function. Returns a vector with first entry zero (falsey in R) for invalid input.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP08jR6dYs7o8IzMnVaO4NFcjR9OuWDMnGiiQnKGXm1gBFIi1hdC6htY5tf/TNJI1THSMdEw0dYw0uUA8cwMdCwMdSwNNHUMDzf8A)

Comment: [56 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP08jR6dYs7o8IzMnVaO4NFcjR9OuWDMnGiiQnKGXm1gBFIi1hdC6htY5tf/TNJI1THSMdEw0dYw0uUA8cwMdCwMdSwNNHUMDzf8A)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 17 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

<sub>*Note:* this solution was ready just as the question was put on hold 33 hours ago.</sub>

```
_MḢ$¦S>¥
ç⁹$ÐLẠȧ$
```

A dyadic link returning the list of positive integers or `0`
(an error rather than `0` is also possible by moving `Ạȧ$` from the end of the second line to the end of the first line).

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AS8A0P9qZWxsef//X03huKIkwqZTPsKlCsOn4oG5JMOQTOG6oMinJP///1s0LDIsNF3/Nw)** or see a [test suite](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/e9@GORSqHlgXbHVrKdXj5o8adKocn@DzcteDEcpX/OoeX64erqDxqWpMFxFDUMFcHxmuYo6CmABTIgnJ0de1A3Mj//6Ojo010jGJ1zGJ1oqONdEygLGMdY2SWOYgFVmcKV2cKlwWzTHXA8oYGUAUgUQjHBCIDMwOk1xxJHGYi3EyouAmSOJhtbqBjYaBjaYAwF2yWUWwsAA).

#### How?

```
_MḢ$¦S>¥ - Link 1, single conditional decrement: list a; number m
         -     ...subtracts 1 from the first maximal element of a if sum(a)>m
         -   else subtracts 0 from the first maximal element of a
       ¥ - last two links as a dyad (left=a; right=m)
     S   -   sum(a)
      >  -   greater than m? (1 if it is, 0 otherwise) - call this x
    ¦    - sparse application of:
_        -   body:       subtraction (left=a; right=x)
   $     -   at indexes: last two links as a monad:
 M       -     indexes of maximal elements
  Ḣ      -     head

ç⁹$ÐLẠȧ$ - Link: list a; number m
   ÐL    - loop until the result does not change:
  $      - last two links as a monad:
 ⁹       -   chain's right argument, m
ç        -   call the last link as a dyad (left=current_a; right=m)
       $ - last two links as a monad:
     Ạ   -   all truthy? (0 if any of the final a's elements are 0)
      ȧ  -   logical and (if all were truthy yield the final a, otherwise 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 30 bytes

```
{_2$:+<{\__:e>_@#\(t\F}{;}?}:F
```

This is essentially of a named function, F, that expects a list and a number on the stack and returns a list on the stack.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP1fWPe/Ot5IxUrbpjomPt4q1S7eQTlGoyTGrbbauta@1srtf13B/2gTBaNYBTMA) or [run a test suite](https://tio.run/##S85KzP1fnROvZKWgpJ1f97863kjFStumOiY@3irVLt5BOUajJMatttq61r7Wyu1/XUGtoZnW/2gTBaNYBTOuaCMFEzBtrGCMoM25IPKmUHlTqDiQNlUAyxgagKUUTCFME4goRB9IhzlcDGIG1BSomAlcDMgyN1CwMFCwNACZBAA)

#### Explanation

I'll refer to the list as `l` and the number as `n`.

```
_      e# Copy n.
2$     e# Copy l.
:+     e# Sum l.
<      e# Check if n < sum(l).
{      e# If it is:
 \__   e#  Bring l to the top of stack and make 2 copies of it.
 :e>_  e#  Get the maximum number in l and copy it.
 @#    e#  Bring l back to the top and find the index of max(l) in l.
 \(    e#  Decrement max(l).
 t     e#  Set the element of l at the position of max(l) to max(l)-1.
 \     e#  Swap, so now the top of the stack has the new l just under n.
 F     e#  Call F again on the new l and n.
}{     e# Else:
 ;     e#  Delete n.
}?     e# (end if)
```